# Performance comparison of similar WHERE clauses

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to know that is there any performance difference between the below 2 queries.

Query 1:

```
Select
         personName
From tbl
Where personName = 'Asif'
```

Query2:

```
Select
         personName
From tbl
Where personName = 'Muhammad Asif'
```

the PersonName field is not on index.
I just want to konw that when we search a string that have spaces then sql engine requires more effort/time to execute the query or it behave the same as without spaces.

Shorty:

1. If string is like without spaces but short like Asif or alphanumeric Q1234
2. if string contain spaces like 'Muhammad Asif'
3. if string contain spaces and its bit long like 'My name is Khan'

What will be the impact of sql engine on these search criteria?

Comment: What happens when you profile each one?  Why would spaces be significant?  They have no special meaning beyond being an additional character in the string.  Proper indexing of fields you intend to search on will have vastly more positive impact on your performance than string size will.

Comment: You should open up both queries in ms sql server, and then do a display estimated execution plan on both, then compare the estimated I/O, CPU, and operator cost to get a better sense of what's happening. This can be used for any sql query. Database access paths are specific to each specific db. That being said, the only thing different between the two queries is the length of the string being queried, which most likely will not give you any performance difference between the two.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with estimated. You get a lot more information from actual.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for Muhammad Asif, your first query will not return that record. if you use an equal in your where clause it will only return exact matches.

if you're looking to find records that include the name 'asif', you could use

WHERE personName LIKE '%Asif%' which would return both Asif and Muhammad Asif and any other records that contain Asif. However, LIKE is a fairly resource intensive query

Comment: Well, it depends - if you use `LIKE 'Asif%'` then SQL Server's query optimizer might still use an index (if there were one on that column). However, if you use `LIKE '%asif%'` then you're **never** going to have an index being used and thus the query will be slow (basically a full table scan)